# julia Jupyter on() interaction error message

Tags: julia, jupyter, interaction

Trying to use three sliders and display the
sum of their values with Julia in a Jupyter notebook
I get some complicated errors
(the update of the textbox displaying the sum seems to work o.k.).
The code:

```
using IJulia
using Interact

function doIt(x)
  newVal = sl1[] + sl2[] + sl3[] 
  tb[] = "val = $newVal"
end;


tb = textbox("***")

sl1 = slider(1:100, label = "s1", value = 40) 
sl2 = slider(1:100, label = "s2", value = 50) 
sl3 = slider(1:100, label = "s3", value = 60) 


display(sl1)
display(sl2)
display(sl3)

display(tb)


on(doIt, sl1)
on(doIt, sl2)
on(doIt, sl3)
```

the output in Jupyter:

```
ObserverFunction `doIt` operating on Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :div), Any[Scope(Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :div), Any[Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :div), Any[Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :label), Any["s3"], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"interact ", :style=>Dict{Any, Any}(:padding=>"5px 10px 0px 10px")))], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"interact-flex-row-left")), Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :div), Any[Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :input), Any[], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:max=>100, :min=>1, :attributes=>Dict{Any, Any}(:type=>"range", Symbol("data-bind")=>"numericValue: index, valueUpdate: 'input', event: {change: function (){this.changes(this.changes()+1)}}", "orient"=>"horizontal"), :step=>1, :className=>"slider slider is-fullwidth", :style=>Dict{Any, Any}()))], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"interact-flex-row-center")), Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :div), Any[Node{DOM}(DOM(:html, :p), Any[], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:attributes=>Dict("data-bind"=>"text: formatted_val")))], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"interact-flex-row-right"))], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"interact-flex-row interact-widget")), Dict{String, Tuple{AbstractObservable, Union{Nothing, Bool}}}("changes"=>(Observable(0), nothing), "index"=>(Observable(60), nothing)), Set{String}(), nothing, Asset[Asset("js", "knockout", "/home/std/.julia/packages/Knockout/HReiN/src/../assets/knockout.js"), Asset("js", "knockout_punches", "/home/std/.julia/packages/Knockout/HReiN/src/../assets/knockout_punches.js"), Asset("js", nothing, "/home/std/.julia/packages/InteractBase/LJXv3/src/../assets/all.js"), Asset("css", nothing, "/home/std/.julia/packages/InteractBase/LJXv3/src/../assets/style.css"), Asset("css", nothing, "/home/std/.julia/packages/Interact/PENUy/src/../assets/bulma_confined.min.css")], Dict{Any, Any}("changes"=>Any[JSString("(function (val){return (val!=this.model[\"changes\"]()) ? (this.valueFromJulia[\"changes\"]=true, this.model[\"changes\"](val)) : undefined})")], "index"=>Any[JSString("(function (val){return (val!=this.model[\"index\"]()) ? (this.valueFromJulia[\"index\"]=true, this.model[\"index\"](val)) : undefined})")]), ConnectionPool(Channel{Any}(32), Set{AbstractConnection}(), GenericCondition{ReentrantLock}(IntrusiveLinkedList{Task}(Task (runnable) @0x00007a6c4ce84c90, Task (runnable) @0x00007a6c4ce84c90), ReentrantLock(nothing, 0x00000000, 0x00, GenericCondition{SpinLock}(IntrusiveLinkedList{Task}(nothing, nothing), SpinLock(0)), (1, 134605610938864, 134605467222224)))), JSString[JSString("function () {\n    var handler = (function (ko, koPunches) {\n    ko.punches.enableAll();\n    ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue = {\n        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {\n            var stringified = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));\n            stringified.subscribe(function(value) {\n                var val = parseFloat(value);\n                if (!isNaN(val)) {\n                    valueAccessor()(val);\n                }\n            });\n            valueAccessor().subscribe(function(value) {\n                var str = JSON.stringify(value);\n                if ((str == \"0\") && ([\"-0\", \"-0.\"].indexOf(stringified()) >= 0))\n                     return;\n                 if ([\"null\", \"\"].indexOf(str) >= 0)\n                     return;\n                stringified(str);\n            });\n            ko.applyBindingsToNode(\n                element,\n                {\n                    value: stringified,\n                    valueUpdate: allBindings.get('valueUpdate'),\n                },\n                context,\n            );\n        }\n    };\n    var json_data = {\"formatted_vals\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\",\"12\",\"13\",\"14\",\"15\",\"16\",\"17\",\"18\",\"19\",\"20\",\"21\",\"22\",\"23\",\"24\",\"25\",\"26\",\"27\",\"28\",\"29\",\"30\",\"31\",\"32\",\"33\",\"34\",\"35\",\"36\",\"37\",\"38\",\"39\",\"40\",\"41\",\"42\",\"43\",\"44\",\"45\",\"46\",\"47\",\"48\",\"49\",\"50\",\"51\",\"52\",\"53\",\"54\",\"55\",\"56\",\"57\",\"58\",\"59\",\"60\",\"61\",\"62\",\"63\",\"64\",\"65\",\"66\",\"67\",\"68\",\"69\",\"70\",\"71\",\"72\",\"73\",\"74\",\"75\",\"76\",\"77\",\"78\",\"79\",\"80\",\"81\",\"82\",\"83\",\"84\",\"85\",\"86\",\"87\",\"88\",\"89\",\"90\",\"91\",\"92\",\"93\",\"94\",\"95\",\"96\",\"97\",\"98\",\"99\",\"100\"],\"changes\":WebIO.getval({\"name\":\"changes\",\"scope\":\"8040069594266069\",\"id\":\"16\",\"type\":\"observable\"}),\"index\":WebIO.getval({\"name\":\"index\",\"scope\":\"8040069594266069\",\"id\":\"15\",\"type\":\"observable\"})};\n    var self = this;\n    function AppViewModel() {\n        for (var key in json_data) {\n            var el = json_data[key];\n            this[key] = Array.isArray(el) ? ko.observableArray(el) : ko.observable(el);\n        }\n        \n        [this[\"formatted_val\"]=ko.computed(    function(){\n        return this.formatted_vals()[parseInt(this.index())-(1)];\n    }\n,this)]\n        [this[\"changes\"].subscribe((function (val){!(this.valueFromJulia[\"changes\"]) ? (WebIO.setval({\"name\":\"changes\",\"scope\":\"8040069594266069\",\"id\":\"16\",\"type\":\"observable\"},val)) : undefined; return this.valueFromJulia[\"changes\"]=false}),self),this[\"index\"].subscribe((function (val){!(this.valueFromJulia[\"index\"]) ? (WebIO.setval({\"name\":\"index\",\"scope\":\"8040069594266069\",\"id\":\"15\",\"type\":\"observable\"},val)) : undefined; return this.valueFromJulia[\"index\"]=false}),self)]\n        \n    }\n    self.model = new AppViewModel();\n    self.valueFromJulia = {};\n    for (var key in json_data) {\n        self.valueFromJulia[key] = false;\n    }\n    ko.applyBindings(self.model, self.dom);\n}\n);\n    (WebIO.importBlock({\"data\":[{\"name\":\"knockout\",\"type\":\"js\",\"url\":\"/assetserver/7aa5500172794a8813431ca88172b18d2f534ec8-knockout.js\"},{\"name\":\"knockout_punches\",\"type\":\"js\",\"url\":\"/assetserver/e11a3492e32b7828ce6714d34d626f3e47b65732-knockout_punches.js\"}],\"type\":\"async_block\"})).then((imports) => handler.apply(this, imports));\n}\n")])], Dict{Symbol, Any}(:className=>"field interact-widget"))
```

The output occurs after the slider is moved for the first time.

Comment: You describe this as "some complicated error", but it looks like that's just Jupyter rendering [the output of the call to the `on` method](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Observables.jl/blob/4e78ca2f7c251cde6ceb900baec1e38a424cd9db/src/Observables.jl#L373). Is there some other error that is occurring, or do you just not want that output to be displayed in Jupyter?

Comment: I guess, this part "KERNEL EXCEPTION
MethodError: no method matching doIt(::Int64)" is an error.
Also - if possible - I don't want the output of the call not to be displayed. Thank you!